# ACE Editor multiline regex

Tags: javascript, regex, ace-editor

I'm using ACE Editor to syntax highlight my website's BBCode system, and on the whole it's working well. The only thing that isn't is our equivalent to multiline comments:

```
[nobbcode]
    I am a demo of [b]BBCode[/b].
    Anything in here is shown as plain text, with code left intact,
    allowing people to show how it works.
[/nobbcode]
```

The rule for this is:

```
{
    token:[
        "meta.tag.punctuation.tag-open.xml",
        "meta.tag.tag-name.xml",
        "meta.tag.punctuation.tag-close.xml",
        "comment",
        "meta.tag.punctuation.end-tag-open.xml",
        "meta.tag.tag-name.xml",
        "meta.tag.punctuation.tag-close.xml"
    ],
    regex:/(\[)(nobbcode)(\])([\s\S]*?)(\[\/)(nobbcode)(\])/,
    caseInsensitive:true
},
```

And it works great in an example like this:

```
You can use [nobbcode][b]...[/b][/nobbcode] to designate bold text.
```

where the match is on a single line, but it doesn't seem to like multiline text.

Does ACE not support multi-line regex, and if so should I instead break it down into "start comment, comment, end comment" parts?

Comment: Maybe you already looked at this [2014 google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ace-discuss/fDFUOYghi8E), but, just in case...

Comment: Ah, so it's line-by-line? That would make sense. I find the official documentation very difficult to understand at times... If this is indeed the case, what would be the easiest way to implement the states here? Using push/pop or a separate state, for instance?

Comment: I would use some `isMultiLineComment` to indicate the state I think...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Thomas' comment, I learned that ACE parses line-by-line, and therefore multiline regexes will not work.

I fixed my issue with the following syntax rule:

```
{
    token:[
        "meta.tag.punctuation.tag-open.xml",
        "meta.tag.tag-name.xml",
        "meta.tag.punctuation.tag-close.xml"
    ],
    regex:/(\[)(nobbcode)(\])/,
    caseInsensitive:true,
    push:[
        {
            token:[
                "meta.tag.punctuation.end-tag-open.xml",
                "meta.tag.tag-name.xml",
                "meta.tag.punctuation.tag-close.xml"
            ],
            regex:/(\[\/)(nobbcode)(\])/,
            caseInsensitive:true,
            next:"pop"
        },
        {defaultToken:"comment"}
    ]
},
```

This essentially breaks it down into start-middle-end, applying the "comment" token to the middle part with `defaultToken`.

I just wish ACE were documented better...