# Multi line regular expression search and replace in Ace editor

Tags: regex, angular, ace-editor

Is there any support documentation regarding multi line regular expression search and replace support for ace editor.

Regular expression for multi line search

```
\\begin{.+?}(.*\n.*)*?\\end{(.+?)}
```

And the latex document content against which i want to search is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{fsdfds}
\author{yadu.rvt }
\date{July 2019}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.
There is another theory which states that this has already happened.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe'' \citep{adams1995hitchhiker}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

\n is not working with regular expression search in ace editor. I need to enable multi line regular expression search inside ace editor. Any help please. This is checked and working in https://regex101.com/

Comment: Can you make this a complete question by showing us your regex pattern as well as the text against which you want to search?

Comment: If you need dot to match across newlines, but your editor does not actually support a dot all mode, then try using `[\s\S]*`.  This should match across newlines.

Comment: I have editted the question. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general regex pattern which should work, even if your editor does not support dot all mode:

```
\\begin\{([^}]+)\}[\s\S]*?\\end\{\1\}
```

The idea here is to match a `\begin` marker, and also match *and* capture the type of marker (e.g. `document` or `figure`).  Then, we match across newlines until hitting the first closing `\end` marker.

### Demo

If we wanted to make the pattern more specific, and, e.g., only match a single `figure` section, then we could try:

```
\\begin\{figure\}[\s\S]*?\\end\{figure\}
```

### Demo

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't work with ace editor. please refer this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289002/ace-editor-multiline-regex